# How to check if a semaphore is under WAIT?

Tags: c#, .net, synchronization, semaphore

I am writing in code having global semaphore, `ServerStatusFileSemaphore`. I want to release the semaphore in catch block only when the semaphore has been waited successfully inside try.

My Code is

```
/*Initialization*/
Semaphore ServerStatusFileSemaphore = new Semaphore(1, 1, "ServerStatusFileSemaphore");

/*Use inside function*/
//Location is file directory and is initialized.
try
{
    ServerStatusFileSemaphore.WaitOne();
    using (StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(Location, true))
    {
        SW.WriteLine(Message);
    }
    ServerStatusFileSemaphore.Release(1);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    ServerStatusFileSemaphore.Release(1);
    Console.WriteLine("Problem inside AppendToStatusFile");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the `WaitOne` call *before* the `try`, and put a single `Release` call into a `finally` block (get rid of the others).  That way, you’ll only enter the `try/finally` upon successfully acquiring the semaphore, and you’ll always release it.

Answer (score 1):

According to MSDN, WaitOne() returns

> true if the current instance receives a signal. If the current instance is never signaled, WaitOne never returns

You can therefore handle it with a try/finally starting after it returns.

```
    try
    {
        // do whatever before semaphore needed
        ServerStatusFileSemaphore.WaitOne();
        try
        {
            using (StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(Location, true))
            {
                SW.WriteLine(Message);
            }
            // do whatever while you have the semaphore
        }
        finally
        {
            ServerStatusFileSemaphore.Release(1);
        }
        // do whatever after semaphore released
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // No need to release in here, it was either never acquired or already released
        Console.WriteLine("Problem inside AppendToStatusFile");
    }
```